# jquery compare returning false instead of true

Tags: jquery

while reading label from HTML page using $(this).text and comparing it with a same string, its returning false.

```
var readText = $(this).text(); // assume $(this).text() reads 1234 for you
readText === "1234" //this return false
```

Why this behavior? Also how to fix this so compare will return true.

Comment: You should probably trim the string. `$.trim(readText) === "1234"`

Comment: I find this unlikely if you're properly retrieving the string. Set a breakpoint and look at the actual value, make sure the cars are actually the same instead of just looking the same, etc. If you do all that and still think there's something wrong then set up a jsfiddle. Otherwise I think most people will be rightfully skeptical.

Comment: what is `this`? `.text()` will not work on input elements, and will include the text of any descendant nodes.

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3N4r5/

Comment: @isherwood work fine if there is not withspace in HTML : http://jsfiddle.net/Su75c/1/

Comment: Right, but the OP says to assume otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `1234` is an integer, and `"1234"` is a string. If you use the `===` operator, you check if they both have the same value + the same type. If you just want to check if they have the same value, use `==`.
More information about JavaScript comparison operators: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

If `$(this).text()` *is* a string, you should do `$(this).text().trim`. This will remove whitespace and newlines, which could lead to the comparison returning `false`

Comment: `text` returns a string.

Comment: @undefined then you should first do `$(this).text().trim()` this will remove whitespace and newlines which could cause the comparison to fail

Comment: Yes, I have suggested the jQuery `$.trim` in my comment above. +1 for the trim part.

Comment: @Jonan, you said: "which could lead to the comparison returning false", do you mean - true? as they are both strings. (regarding to example)

Comment: @SergeyBoiko if `$(this).text()` has a newline or whitespace at the end, `readText === "1234"` will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are correct about this.

This simple fiddle claims otherwise: http://jsfiddle.net/e7nKP/1/

The js is like this:

```
$(function () {
    var readText = $('#foo').text();
    console.log(readText === "1234");
});
```

Where `#foo` is a simple div with 1234 as content.